# Need to detect any changes in child component when parent component is open

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to detect if i make any changes in the child component then parent component should know about the changes.

so I have some text editors in the child component and when i make any changes in that text editors then parent component should know about it.

Code that I have tried:

Parent component :

```
@ViewChildren(EditorComponent) editor: EditorComponent;

ngAfterViewChecked(){
  console.info(this.editor.isDirty);
}
```

but this always returns `undefined`.

In child component i have mentioned isdirty as false by default.

Can you please guide me on how to proceed with this.

Comment: aren't you using event binding (@output) to pass the data from child to parent?

Comment: show me the html and component code

Comment: @AkashAgrawal i dont want to use that. I want to use view child and try to get the data

Comment: any specific reason for not using event binding? It's one of the simplest way to pass the data

Comment: @AkashAgrawal i have multiple classes. So its difficult to pass the data and code becomes complicated. So that is the reason i dont want to use

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`@Output Decorator`](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) to send data from child to parent component.

In the child component create an event emitter and pass the value into the event emitter.

```
 @Output() childValueChange = new EventEmitter();

 this.childValueChange.emit(value);
```

In parent component
HTML

```
<app-parent-component (childValueChange)='save($event)'></app-parent-component>
```

Component.ts

```
save(event){
  // Here you will get  the value which child has emitted
  console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: I have actually tried this but it becomes complicated as there are multiple classes in between parent and child. So i want to try using view children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild(EditorComponent) editor: EditorComponent;
```

[`Online Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-output-angular-izmczv)

Comment: i Tried this as well but it still returns underfined.

Comment: Or show us the HTML part of child and parent component!

Comment: Yes this works. but ngAfterViewChecked gets called multiple times. Even when i am loading the screen it keeps on calling ngAfterViewChecked  and post that also it gets called. I want ngAfterViewChecked to be called at the time change is made

Comment: I think every time you view checked this function will trigger, try other methods from lifecycle like `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: ngAfterViewInit will be called only once at the begining and not after i make any changes